# How to access image resource from res/drawable folder in native code?

Tags: android, resources, native, drawable, android-ndk

I have been looking for some method in order to access resources like 
images stored in res/drawable folder. Actually I am searching for some 
procedure similar to our Java code i.e. accessing resources saved in 
res/drawable from the R.drawable class. Is there any thing similar 
technique provided in native code also? If not then there should be 
some alternative to access these resources, kindly tell me what is it. 
Looking for an early reply. Thanks in advance. 
With Regards, 
Atul Prakash Singh

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass a `FileDescriptor` of the resource you are trying to access to the native procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Uri by passing a string to it. Like this:

```
String s = "android.resource://[your_package]/R.drawavle.img";
Uri u = Uri.parse(s);
```

Comment: Can I able to run it in my native code(.cpp). If yes, then which header file I need to include?

Answer (score 0):

```
 getResources().getIdentifier(name,"drawable", getPackageName())
```